# How to add rdlc file to ReportViewer in WPF projects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reportviewer, rdlc

I've added a `ReportViewer` in a `WPF` app via the `XAML` designer of my main window and I'd like to add an existing rdlc file to it.

I'd like my reportviewer to show an empty rdlc file (without the parameters) on startup, and later upon selecting a row from my datagrid (bound to an observablecollection) change its parameters accordingly and show the filled report definition instead of the empty one.

I'll make a button with the selected row as commandparameter and the relevant events and everything, I just need to be able to pass data to the report. I realize it is not an easy question so I'll try to simplify:

1. How to add an existing rdlc file to a ReportViewer (MVVM, WPF) ?
2. I push a button -> relevant command gets the item from my observablecollection as parameter (a row in my datagrid) -> How to pass the data parts of this item to the unfilled (or overwrite if filled of course) parts of the report?

I hope I've been clear. Thanks for the answer in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you set up your initilizeMethod with correct path to the report and dataset name something like this.

```
private void initializeReport()
        {
            this.mform_components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();

            this.ProductBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.mform_components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ProductBindingSource)).BeginInit();

            reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet4";
            reportDataSource1.Value = this.ProductBindingSource;

            this.viewerInstance.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
            this.viewerInstance.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourReport.rdlc";
            this.viewerInstance.ZoomPercent = 95;
            this.windowsFormsHost1.Width = 680;

            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ProductBindingSource)).EndInit();
    }
```

Only thing that should be left is specifing the object you want to se in your report.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource ProductBindingSource;
        private void startReport()
        {
            YourClass item  = (YourClass)DataGridView.SelectedItem;
            this.ProductBindingSource.DataSource = item;

            this.viewerInstance.RefreshReport();
            this.viewerInstance.Refresh();
        }
```

Comment: Oh my god! Works like a charm! Thank you for ending my suffering!

Answer (score 1):

A was developing somethink like that a couple of months ago. 
However it's to much code to post here but have a look at this its completed sample with source Code.
[Advanced-Report-Viewver Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35225/Advanced-Report-Viewer)

Comment: Can I have another question to you? Here is a printscreen of my report: [link](http://s8.postimg.org/3nahbg285/report.jpg) How can I pass data from my `ObservableCollection` to the highlighted part of my DataSet4 and eventually to every part? Thanks!