# Pass data from datagrid to reportviewer dataset

Tags: wpf, datagrid, dataset, reportviewer, rdlc

I have an app in C# WPF with an existing `.rdlc` file added to a `ReportViewer`. The report already has datasets. Here is a printscreen: [link](http://s8.postimg.org/3nahbg285/report.jpg). Now, I have a `DataGrid` that's bound to an `ObservableCollection`. How can I pass data from the collection to the fields of the dataset? The parts of the items of the `ObservableCollection` have the same type as the fields of the datasets but have different names. So I want the user to be able to select a single row from the `DataGrid` and the records of this row (parts of an item of the `ObservableCollection`) to fill the appropriate fields of the dataset thus showing a populated report in my `ReportViewer`. And whenever the user selects a different row, the data in the report should change accordingly. I hope I've been clear. I've read about `IEnumerable` and `List<T>` set as datasource but I don't get that. I just want to overwrite the fields of my dataset as if they were parts of a structure or a class and then present them in the formatted report. Can this be done in a similar, simple way? Because I don't know why I would want to take my item from the `ObservableCollection` and make a `List<>` out of it. But in case I chose this option should the items of the `List<>` have the same name and type as the fields in the dataset?

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: See the accepted answer [here][1]. Hope it helps. :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709811/how-to-add-rdlc-file-to-reportviewer-in-wpf-projects

Comment: @cod3n00b Yeah, it helped, that's my post but thanks anyway :D