# Populate an ObservableCollection of objects as a datasource in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, reportviewer, observablecollection

I have a problem in dealing with the ReportViewer in WPF. I have a datagridview which is bound to an observable collection of a specific object. Whenever I clicked the Generate Report button. I want to populate all those objects inside the collection into the ReportViewer which displays the objects per page. I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709811/how-to-add-rdlc-file-to-reportviewer-in-wpf-projects) how to populate each objects in a datagrid but now I need to populate all the objects in the collection per page.

**EDITED:** I already have my own .rdlc which I created manually(not using the report wizard)

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: have you looked into a tablix

Comment: It seems that It won't solve my problem. From what I have understand is that it needs an SQL Server. I only need to populate every objects in the collection per page in the rdlc that I have made recently. :(

Comment: Why don't you show some code so we can have a better understanding of what you need.